# WCF web service - how can I view XML request and response inside my app?

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I am writing a C# WinForms application that consumes a web service using WCF.  I would like to be able to display the XML request and response in the application in real-time as the calls are happening.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably want to use / write a custom MessageInspector:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Another handy way to look at the raw communication is to enable tracing (but this would log the messages outside your application which might not suit your needs):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx