# WCF Service: Application Crash

Tags: wcf-client

I have a massive problem: I have a WPF application that makes a WcF service call. That call functions well if the user is an administrative user. It crashes simply without a chance to catch an exception (none is reported in Windows event logs too). What user right is required to have the service beeing called as a standard user in Windows Vista?

Thanks

Comment: That's an interesting one... Have you tried hooking up diagnostics to see how far the call goes?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152306/wcf-web-service-how-can-i-view-xml-request-and-response-inside-my-app/3152327#3152327

Comment: Could this a permissions issue in the temporary directory?

Comment: I can read and write in the temp dir. Actually I do this before calling the wcf service. But logging shows me that it is the wcf call (last log entry is now calling the wcf service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved through changes on the server side. I don't know the reasons nor do I know what changed. A colleague deployed a new version and: there we go...