# Get Request / Response XML from WCF webservice

Tags: .net, xml, wcf, web-services

I'm creating an API site for our clients where they can click on a public method and they can see the request XML and the Response XML.  Similar to the way SoapUI works.

I've hunted all over the internet and I can't seem to find a solution that will help me to get the XML request or the XML response from my webservice.

I've read a lot about tracing etc, but all I want to do (in simple terms) is to get the XML request and the XML response from a method.

I've added the webservice into my app as a service reference and I've hunted through the various property and methods that are exposed to me but with no joy.

I'm using .net and MVC 4.

Comment: Are you trying to read the real-time request/response XML that is communicated from/to your service or are you trying to generate an example XML for a service request/response operation?

Comment: Hi Martin, just trying to provide examples to be honest.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152306/wcf-web-service-how-can-i-view-xml-request-and-response-inside-my-app

Comment: All information about the 'request/response' xml for a SOAP based web service can be found in it's "WSDL" or "Metadata Exchange" endpoint. Just like viewing the ".svc" page in a browser (which creates the documentation page), it uses this WSDL to generate XML examples from the provided Schema's included/embedded in this WSDL/MEX

Comment: Hi Edwin, kind of.  I did look at message inspectors, I wasn't convinced that it did what I wanted.

Comment: MessageInspectors could work to "scan/modify" the request response XML passing by in real-time, i don't think this is what the OP is after. So using the messageinspector path sounds like the wrong way to go for the functionality required.

Comment: Hi Marvin, " it uses this WSDL to generate XML examples from the provided Schema's included/embedded in this WSDL/MEX" - that's what I'm looking to do as well.

Comment: Have a look at "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework{64}?\{version}\Config\DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx". This is the default helppage generator for WCF SOAP services. It might contain the information you are after.